# Accessing control inside a ribbon in Outlook using VSTO

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto

i am trying to access a label in builtIn ribbon and trying to change its visibility inside a background worker. But its not working.

My Code is

```
Globals.Ribbons.MailReadItemRibbon.verifyLabel.Visible = true;
```

If anyone know what i am doing wrong. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should't access any UI controls from secondary threads. It is allowed to make any changes to the UI on the main thread only. You may consider using the [Control.Invoke](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.invoke(v=vs.110).aspx) method which executes a delegate on the thread that owns the control's underlying window handle.

Second, the Fluent UI (aka Ribbon UI) is a static thing from its birth. The only possible dynamism is callbacks. So, I'd recommend using callbacks with the IRibbonUI's [Invalidate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.core.iribbonui.invalidate.aspx) or [InvalidateControl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.core.iribbonui.invalidatecontrol.aspx) methods instead. Take a look at the following articles for the sample code:

- [Chapter 11: Creating Dynamic Ribbon Customizations (1 of 2)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd548010(v=office.12).aspx)
- [Chapter 11: Creating Dynamic Ribbon Customizations (2 of 2)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd548011(v=office.12).aspx)

For each of the callbacks the add-in implements, the responses are cached. For example, if an add-in writer implements the getImage callback procedure for a button, the function is called once, the image loads, and then if the image needs to be updated, the cached image is used instead of recalling the procedure. This process remains in-place until the add-in signals that the cached values are invalid by using the Invalidate method, at which time, the callback procedure is again called and the return response is cached.

The Fluent UI (aka Ribbon UI) is described in depth in the following series of articles:

- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 1 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338202(v=office.12).aspx)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 2 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338199(v=office.12).aspx)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 3 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa722523(v=office.12).aspx)